# Show that $\bar g=\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^Ng(x_i,y_i)=g(\bar x,\bar y)$

Tags: statistics, means

I have been asked to show that: $$\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^Ng(x_i,y_i)=g(\bar x,\bar y)$$
Where $$\bar g=\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^Ng(x_i,y_i)$$

A clue given in the problem sheet is:

$$g(x_i,y_i)-g(\bar x,\bar y)=(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})_y(x_i-\bar x)+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})_x(y_i-\bar y)$$

Clearly this rearranges to give:
$$g(x_i,y_i)=(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})_y(x_i-\bar x)+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})_x(y_i-\bar y)+g(\bar x,\bar y)$$
which may be plugged into the first equation:
$$\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^N[(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})_y(x_i-\bar x)+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})_x(y_i-\bar y)+g(\bar x,\bar y)]$$

$$\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^N(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})_y(x_i-\bar x)+\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^N(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})_x(y_i-\bar y)+\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^Ng(\bar x,\bar y)$$

$g(x_i,y_i)$ is contant so:

$$\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^N(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x})_y(x_i-\bar x)+\frac1 N \sum_{i=1}^N(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y})_x(y_i-\bar y)+g(\bar x,\bar y)$$

But I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: This is clearly false for general $g$, I think $g$ would need to be somewhat _harmonic_ for this to be true. counter-example: $g(x,y) = x^2$, $x_i \in \{-1, 1\}$ then $\bar g = 1 \ne 0 = g(0,\cdot)$

Comment: $g$ denotes a function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: I don't know, this is the question on a problem sheet that I have to do over the holiday. The lecture hand out seems to suggest that partial derivatives might be useful.

Comment: It assumes that values for $x$ are normally distributed i.e. it follows the normal distribution function

Comment: @AlexR The result holds for general $g$ assuming at most $C^1.$

Comment: @mfl Where is the flaw in my counter-example? I even have $g\in C^\infty$

Comment: @AlexR You are right. I have made a mistake.

Comment: @mfl Where was it, I didn't find it yet ^^

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \overline{x}}{\partial x_i}=\frac 1n \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ is not correct.

Comment: Question has now been edited with how the solution is meant to be started

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is certainly false. We can resort to $g(x)$ by letting $g(x, \cdot)$ constant.
Take $g(x) = x^2, x_1 = 1, x_2 = -1$ then
$$\bar g = \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^2 g(x_i) = \frac12 \cdot (1+1) = 1 \ne 0 = g(0) = g(\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i) = g(\bar x)$$

Actually the proposition implies that $g$ is more or less affine:
$$\frac12 (g(x) + g(x')) = g(\frac12(x+x')) \qquad\forall\ x,x' \\
\stackrel{x'=0}\Rightarrow \frac12 g(x) + \frac12 g(0) = g(\frac12 x) \qquad \forall\ x$$

Comment: Question has now been edited with how the solution is meant to be started. Please help.

Comment: @user3764899 You can't prove the proposition in any way because **it is not true**. There is no correct possible proof for it. Point out the error to the person who gave the assignment, or reveal additional constraints on $g$ (_affine_ will work, for example, i.e. $g(x,y) = axy+bx+cy+d$).